# Add two array elements using loop

Tags: java

I am trying a task with arrays: add two elements and check if the sum is less than or equal to 50. If the condition is satisfied, it should break.

Example program:

```
public class HelloWorld {

     public static void main(String []args)
     {
         int[] nums = new int[2];

         for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
         {
             nums[i] = i + 1;
             System.out.println(i);
         }
         System.out.println(nums[1]);
         System.out.println(nums[2]);

         if  (nums[0]+nums[1]<=50)
         {
             System.out.printf("Sucessfully finished");
         }     
     }
}
```

Of course, my program is not working. I want `i` value to store in the two elements
`nums[0] = 1` and `nums[1] = 2`. I also want to add these two elements and check if the sum is less than or equal to 50. I have allocated two elements in the array which means `nums` want to add and check the current two elements of `i` and clear and adds next two elements and check if its less than or equal to 50.

```
nums[0]=1;
nums[1]=2; check <=50 . fails clear the the array elements and store next i value           
nums[0]=3;
nums[1]=4; check <=50 . fails clear the the array elements and store next i value              
...                        
nums[0]=25;                      
nums[1]=26; check <=50 .
```

Comment: Important note: `<=` denotes *less than or equal* while `>=` denotes *greater than or equal*.

Comment: In your if statement you have "(nums[1]+nums[2]<=50)". When using arrays/lists the first element is always 0. So your array with two ints can be accessed using nums[0] and nums[1] (you have actually mentioned this later one). For what you are doing I'd recommend you just use two variables noOne and noTwo. It would make it easier to read.

Comment: Don't forget the two System.out.println() statements too. :)

Comment: I think you have your logic backwards.  `nums[0]=1;nums[1]=2;check <= 50` should be *true* since `1 + 2 = 3; 3 <= 50`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do this but here is a nifty trick that solves exactly this kind of problem.

```
int[] nums = new int[2];

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    nums[i % nums.length] = i + 1;

    if (nums[0] + nums[1] <= 50) {
        System.out.println("sum is less than or equal to 50");
        break;
    }
}
```

What the mod operator (`%`) does is calculate the remainder of `i` based on the array's length. This ensures that `i` goes from 0 to 99 but the array index always "resets" and stays within the range of the array. For example after `i == 0` and `i == 1`, `i` will be incremented to out of bounds at `i == 2` but `2 % 2 == 0`. When `i == 3`, `3 % 2 == 1` and so on.

But as a side note, the condition you've described (*"if the sum is less than or equal to 50...it should break"*) will be satisfied immediately (sums `1` at `nums[0]` and `0` at `nums[1]`) and the loop will not execute past the first iteration (`i == 0`). I'm not sure that's what you are wanting. Do you mean "*not* less than or equal to 50"?

```
int[] nums = new int[2];

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    nums[i % nums.length] = i + 1;

    if (nums[0] + nums[1] > 50) {
        System.out.println("sum was NOT less than or equal to 50");
        break;
    }
}
```

As an alternate solution finding this result can be very much shortened to the following while loop:

```
int i = 0;

// note sum of two consecutive integers will never be even (never 50)
while (i + ++i < 50);

System.out.println("min increments with sum > 50 was " + (i - 1) + " and " + i);
```

The output is `min increments with sum > 50 was 25 and 26`.

Comment: head shot .. code works and your explanation was good thanks for the clarity

Comment: how to check the value inside the nums[0] and nums[1] .. bcoz i am getting 1 and 0

Comment: Not sure what you mean "check the value"? They will (correctly) be 1 and 0 on the first iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, you need 1 more for loop, to go about checking each  num[i] + num[i+1].  You can do it in a single for loop as well, but kept the code as simple as possible for your clarity.(As you are new to java programming ;))

```
public class HelloWorld{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] nums = new int[100];

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        nums[i] = i + 1;
        System.out.println(i);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++) {
        System.out.println(nums[i]);
        System.out.println(nums[i+1]);

        if (nums[i] + nums[i+1] == 50) {
            System.out.printf("Successfully finished");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: i tried with two loop .. as you mentioned above.. but i want to make it in a single loop ... this is what i am trying for 2 days

Comment: I think OP just wants `nums` to have two elements, and in the loop, assign (I think) `i` to one element and `i+1` to the other, then check if the sum is less than 50. (Rather than populating `nums` with 100 elements, then checking those elements, which is what your code does.)

Comment: Further nitpick.  The sum of two consecutive integers will never equal 50, so your test condition will never be met.  The closest you'll get will be `24 + 25 == 49` and then `25 + 26 == 51`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you meant. Have a try.

```
public static void main(String[]    args) {
    int[] nums = new int[100];
    nums[0] =1;
    for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
        nums[i] = i + 1;
        if ((nums[i] +nums[i-1]) >= 50) {
             System.out.printf("Successfully finished");
        } 
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure on what your end goal is. If you just want to add two numbers (i, and i+1) and see if they are less than 50 then you can use this.

```
for (int i =0; i < 100; i++) {
    int j = i+1;
    int total = i+j;
    if((i+(i+1)) < 50) {
        System.out.println("Numbers '" + i + "' and '" + j + "' equal '" + total + "'.");
    }
}
```

This will print out all the pairs of numbers that add to less than 50 along with what they add to.

I accept that you're probably wanting something more. :)